# Display only 2 decimal places in MySQL (phpMyAdmin) but retain all decimal places for calculations

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have several tables in my MySQL database where I use Float type of columns, now based on these columns I have several other calculated columns too. I want to be able to continue using float columns for all my calculations and retain the "accuracy" yet when I see the results in phpMyAdmin, I want to see just 2 decimal places so that it looks neat.

`TRUNCATE(0.16666, 2)` would not work because it will evaluate to 0.16, however I still want to continue using 0.16666 for all my calculations.

`ROUND(0.16666, 2)` would evaluate to 0.17.

What I am looking for is for MySQL to continue using 0.16666 for any subsequent calculations, however when I select/display the table in phpMyAdmin it neatly displays just two decimal palces. Can you please advise.

Comment: for calculations you need different and for seeing you need diffrent what is saved that only willl be visible its not possible. you have to save like  0.16666 annd when need ed two decimal places do `select tochar(colname,'99.99')`;

Comment: In this case do the rounding in the application code, just before displaying the value.

Comment: You seem to want your query tool to auto format float type columns for display using 2 dp, regardless of how many dp the data is stored as in the database, in a similar fashion to a query tool that has a default date format setting whereby date columns are presented in the format of your choice. 

If phpmyadmin doesn't have a way (in the settings) of specifying that you want float/decimal columns to be formatted as 2 decimal places you're going to need to look for a query tool that does.

StackOverflow has specific rules against questions seeking software recommendations though..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because answers would have to recommend particular MySQL query software, and "recommend me a" questions are off topic

Comment: (Notwithstanding what I said the above, you can just use those functions every time you select data in phpmyadmin: Using TRUNC or ROUND in the select list part of your query does not alter the underlying data. MySQL will use th precise form and you format your data when you select it in the outermost select query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do this with just the tables, you have to decide if you want the precision or the rounded results. 
If you want to columns with roundings create VIEWS for displaying your table.

Comment: Thank you @halliballi. I think I will have to bite the bullet and use VIEWS, I wanted to avoid it as they use up space on the database.